# Servlet part file get deleted automatically before request is completed

Tags: tomcat, servlets, file-upload, multipartform-data, servlet-3.0

I am using servlet 3.0 on Tomat 8.0.8 to upload files. For uploading files, I was able to get hold of the Part(file), and the temporary file was created under the tomcat. So far so good. But when I try to copy the file at one point during the same HTTP request, the temporary file has been deleted already. The part is not garbage collected, and the file should be there.

What is going on here? Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Was you relying on (default) OS-managed temporary file location? Try explicitly specifying a custom temporary file location via e.g. `@MultipartConfig(location="/var/web/temp")` and let me know if that works. Regardless, Tomcat 8.0.8 is relatively old. Try upgrading to latest to see if you didn't actually face a Tomcat specific bug which was already fixed for long.

Comment: The temporary files created under tomcat home are not OS managed. I will try the latest version of Tomcat. Thanks.